# Read data from other Excel file after opening the Excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to open an Excel file and copy its data to my other workbook. I was able to open the file through file dialog. How am I suppose to get the data copied on the Excel sheet?

```
Sub selectfile()
    Dim strFileToOpen As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim count As Integer

    strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
                    (Title:="Please choose a file to open", _
                    FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xls* (*.xls*),")
    If strFileToOpen = False Then
        MsgBox "No file selected.", vbExclamation, "Sorry!"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=strFileToOpen
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Option Explicit

 Sub selectfile()
 Dim strFileToOpen As String
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim count As Integer

 strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
 (Title:="Please choose a file to open", _
 FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xls* (*.xls*),")   
 If strFileToOpen = False Then
 MsgBox "No file selected.", vbExclamation, "Sorry!"
Exit Sub
Else
Workbooks.Open Filename:=strFileToOpen
'HERE
activesheet.name = "Copy Sheet"
Sheets("Copy Sheet").Range("A1:" & Sheets("Copy Sheet").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address).Copy Destination:=Sheets("ENTER YOUR SHEET NAME HERE").Range("A1")
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to be aware of the sheet names - in this instance,  sheet you would like to copy from, is the sheet you just copied in, whereas the destination sheet is the "ENTER YOUR SHEET NAME HERE".

Comment: There are multiple approaches, I would recommend anything from Ron De Bruin - https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win001.htm

Comment: You have not placed the line correclty, you are trying to copy before you opend the workbook. This line needs to be after `Workbooks.Open Filename:=strFileToOpen`

Comment: I do not know the filename as it is selected by the user themselves through the file dialog

Comment: @RachelChia if you do not know the file name, then when you upload the sheet, input - activesheet.name = "Copy sheet" ...

Comment: @Lowpar sorry i dun really understand. Would you explain more?

Comment: In this instance, when the sheet is uploaded to the Excel, the name will automatically change to "Copy Sheet". However, at the moment the code only opens a workbook, it does not have the capacity to allow the user to select which sheet to upload, that would be more complicated. I would advise you to search RonDeBruin's website, this will explain more.